# Getting error while trying to record voice in Android

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am trying to record audio using media recorder in Android. My code is generating output file but when I am playing it in "MX player" or "VLC media player" it is playing but no sound.

```
package com.sid.newApp;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    Button b;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override   
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("mnt/sdcard/rec.3gp");
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

       try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        mRecorder.start();
    }



    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To correctly save your record you need to stop recording using `mRecorder.stop()` and `mRecorder.reset()` if you want to use it again. For more information see: [android.media.MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)